# save excel worksheet with empty strings instead of Nonetype with python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i have multiple .xlsx files with empty cells that i need to have empty strings instead. when i do it manually, i just put a single quote in each cell which keeps the cell empty but sets it as a string. i want to automate this process with python (and the openpyxl module) but i can't get it quite right. I tried both entering an empty string and entering a single quote, both failed me for different reasons.

this was my first try:

```
...
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for column in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=column)

        # fixes cells with no value
        if cell.value == None:
            cell.value = ''
...
wb.save('new_file_name.xlsx')
```

during the run before the save, the type of the value was NoneType and it was changed successfully to str, but the new file created by the save function has reverted the empty string back to an empty cell, even the ones I did manually.

my secont attempt was to insert a single quote:

```
...
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row):
    for column in range(1, sheet.max_column):
        cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=column)

        # fixes cells with no value
        if cell.value == None:
            cell.value = '\''
...
wb.save('new_file_name.xlsx')
```

this try resulted an excel file in which every empty cell was replaced by a single quote, but the quotes where showing, unlike when manually inserting single quote, which means it wasn't empty.

is there a way to define an empty cell as a string using python in excel?

Comment: No, empty cells are numbers by default: in XML you cannot differentiate between `None` and "".

Comment: @CharlieClark in excel you definitely can, and openpyxl definitely picks up on that. every cell that i manually typed a single quote in was recognized, both in excel, sql manager, and python as an empty string. for example, in python `cell.value` returned '' and `type(cell.value)` returnd STR, while other empty cells returned nothing for `cell.value` and `NoneType` for `type(cell.value)`, so there is an obvious difference between '' and None, at least in .xsxl files.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe use `if x is None`?
I think NoneType objects are a bit special so == doesn't work.
Maybe check [real python](https://realpython.com/null-in-python/)?

Comment: The problem isn't finding the empty cells. cell.value == None works fine. the problem is changing them to be empty string type cells i a way that will stay after saving. its very specific to the way python communicates with excel.